# SQL query to calculate student demographics?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have only one table, called Students. I have columns for student ID and their race/ethnicity.

This is so simple, but I can’t figure it out: I need to calculate the Number and percentage of students in each race/ethnicity.

So, ultimately, I’d like a table that has one column as the race/ethnicity, another column that is the count of students in that category, and a final column that has the percentage of the total.

I know how to get a count of each race/ethnicity separately, but is there a way to do it all on one query like this?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select ethnicity, count(*) as num_students
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from t
group by ethnicity;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.

Comment: Thanks! That’s really helpful!